# Module to allow multiple paths for a single node?

Tags: 6, path-aliases, uri

Is there a module that would allow me to define multiple paths for a single node? (Not just one node; I need to do this for multiples.) For example, I need to be able to access http://www.example.com/node/153 via both http://www.example.com/tracks/big-picture and http://www.example.com/big-picture.

I need to be able to define at least one of the paths manually, i.e. not using a pattern.

Comment: I'd be curious to know who downvoted this and why. It's a perfectly legitimate question, especially for people not intimately familiar with Drupal admin settings.

Comment: Leaving a comment, you are not notifying the down-voters. Keep in mind that the tooltip of the button for down-voting says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already do this using core's Path module in Drupal 6. If memory serves, it should be in admin/build/path/add. Simply create two aliases that both point to node/153.

I should caution, however, that this may raise red flags with search engines. They typically frown on duplicate content, and your SERP rankings will likely suffer as a result.

Comment: Thanks. All of our content is available only after login, so we're not particularly concerned with search engines.

Comment: Either way, I figure the information will be helpful to those with similar issues later on down the line. :]  Glad I could help.